# How to convert Lagarith .avi videos to MP4 using WinFF

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-codecs, lossless

I have a bunch of .avi videos encoded with Lagarith codec. We would like to convert them in to a lossless .MP4 format so that they could be easily played on html. I want to keep video specifications remain the same if it's possible and just convert the video to MP4.

I tried WinFF and also some manually written FFmpeg codes [without any specific reference to the Lagarith codec] but they all create a video which is not playable (neither with Windows Player nor with the HTML5 player). Also, FFmpeg returns exceptions like bellow.

**Edit:**
Here is the FFmpeg code generated by WinFF, this code gives me the following Exception:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinFF\ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "C:\Desktop\Videos\input.avi" -f mp4 -r 29.97 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -vf scale=640:480 -b:v 1000k -aspect 4:3 -flags +loop -cmp chroma -b:v 1250k -maxrate 1500k -bufsize 4M -bt 256k -refs 1 -bf 3 -coder 1 -me_method umh -me_range 16 -subq 7 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp8x8+partb8x8 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -level 30 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qcomp 0.6 -trellis 2 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 112k -ar 48000 -ac 2 "C:\Desktop\Videos\output.mp4"
```

---

[image]

**2nd Edit:**
Here is the entire exception that I receive:

```
    C:\Users\Desktop\Videos>"c:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -y -i 300
4_KDSmall-08_02_2013-11_43_34_415.avi -crf 26 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -
acodec libvo_aacenc -ac 1 -ar 16000 -b:a 32000 3004_KDSmall-08_02_2013-11_43_34_
415.mp4
ffmpeg version N-62439-g5e379cd Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 13 2014 22:08:47 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable
-zlib
  libavutil      52. 76.100 / 52. 76.100
  libavcodec     55. 58.103 / 55. 58.103
  libavformat    55. 37.100 / 55. 37.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
  libavfilter     4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from '3004_KDSmall-08_02_2013-11_43_34_415.avi':
  Duration: 00:15:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 328 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: lagarith (LAGS / 0x5347414C), rgb24, 320x244, 326 kb/s,
7.50 tbr, 7.50 tbn, 7.50 tbc
Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) specified for output file #0 (3004_KD
Small-08_02_2013-11_43_34_415.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most li
kely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or
that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any
stream.
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] profile High, level 1.2
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] 264 - core 142 r2409 d6b4e63 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 dec
imate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b
_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=
7 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=26.0 qcomp=0.6
0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '3004_KDSmall-08_02_2013-11_43_34_415.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.37.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 320x24
4, q=-1--1, 15360 tbn, 7.50 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (lagarith -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1024 fps=0.0 q=27.0 size=      17kB time=00:02:08.80 bitrate=   1.1kbits/
frame= 1947 fps=1943 q=27.0 size=     234kB time=00:04:11.86 bitrate=   7.6kbits
frame= 2695 fps=1794 q=27.0 size=     659kB time=00:05:51.60 bitrate=  15.4kbits
frame= 3971 fps=1983 q=27.0 size=     680kB time=00:08:41.73 bitrate=  10.7kbits
frame= 5256 fps=2101 q=27.0 size=     702kB time=00:11:33.06 bitrate=   8.3kbits
frame= 6074 fps=2023 q=27.0 size=    1018kB time=00:13:22.13 bitrate=  10.4kbits
frame= 6343 fps=1810 q=27.0 size=    1625kB time=00:13:58.00 bitrate=  15.9kbits
frame= 6588 fps=1644 q=27.0 size=    2247kB time=00:14:30.66 bitrate=  21.1kbits
[lagarith @ 0000000004378fc0] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0x24
[lagarith @ 00000000043796c0] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0x38
[lagarith @ 000000000437a700] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0x4c
[lagarith @ 000000000437d740] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0x60
[lagarith @ 000000000437e760] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0x74
[lagarith @ 0000000007fcb800] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0x88
[lagarith @ 0000000007fcc820] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0x9c
[lagarith @ 0000000007fd0860] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0xb0
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome

[lagarith @ 0000000007fd0ce0] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0xc4
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome

[lagarith @ 0000000004378fc0] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0xd8
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome

[lagarith @ 00000000043796c0] Unsupported Lagarith frame type: 0xec
frame= 6750 fps=1524 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2881kB time=00:14:59.73 bitrate=  26.2kbit
s/s
video:2802kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: 2.842291%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] frame I:29    Avg QP: 8.05  size:  2113
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] frame P:1874  Avg QP:11.85  size:   799
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] frame B:4847  Avg QP:13.60  size:   270
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  6.0%  8.6% 84.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] mb I  I16..4: 82.8%  4.8% 12.4%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.2%  0.3%  P16..4:  5.5%  4.9
%  5.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:84.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.1%  B16..8:  2.9%  2.2
%  1.4%  direct: 0.7%  skip:92.7%  L0:55.4% L1:38.8% BI: 5.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] 8x8 transform intra:13.7% inter:12.4%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 21.9% 42.5% 34.9% inter: 2
.7% 5.4% 4.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] i16 v,h,dc,p: 81%  9%  8%  2%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 14% 49%  2%  3%
 4%  3%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 14% 34%  4%  4%
 5%  4%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] i8c dc,h,v,p: 72% 12% 12%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.1% UV:0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] ref P L0: 42.5%  5.1% 29.3% 23.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] ref B L0: 52.8% 37.8%  9.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] ref B L1: 82.3% 17.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000004288320] kb/s:25.50
```

Any body could help me easily doing this conversion?

Comment: So you haven't provided any code, so I'm not sure how anyone can help.

Comment: You are right @ErikPhilips ,
I've just edited the text and added the FFmpeg script to it.

Comment: I've added the complete errors here

Comment: Thanks. How was the input file created? Can you provide a small sample file that shows this behavior so the issue can be duplicated?

Comment: The input file is a lossless .avi video, created using Lagarith codec. As far as we could understand the problem is because FFmpeg is not implemented Encoder/Decoder for Lagarith!!
I'm looking to find a way to have this conversion in an automated manner, so I'm ready to use Matlab if it's possible.